# How to get the records for today in App Engine (JAVA) Datastore?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, datetime

I have a datetime property in my entity on Google App Engine. When I insert a new record, i set this property with :

```
Date date = new Date();
newEntity.setProperty("dateTime", date);
```

How can I query the records that have been saved today using datetime property?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the Datastore or a cloud service?

Answer (score 2):

Execute a query on your entity, filtering by the `dateTime` property.

First calculate the time of the start of today, something like this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); // You might wanna get instance based on user's time zone
c.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0 );
c.set( Calendar.MINUTE, 0 );
c.set( Calendar.SECOND, 0 );
c.set( Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0 );
Date dayStart = c.getTime();
```

And filter for entities whose `dateTime >= dayStart`, somehow like this:

```
Query q = new Query( "YourEntityName" );
q.setFilter( new FilterPredicate( "dateTime", FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL, dayStart ) );

// And execute the query:
DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
for ( final Entity e : ds.prepare( q ).asIterable() ) {
    // Do something with the entity
}
```

Comment: Note that in real life "today" is timezone dependent. To make this really useable, client should provide his timezone and server should take it into account.

Comment: @PeterKnego Yes, you're right. I wanted to mention that but forgot about it while I was writing the answer. Added it.